# Query how many times a link been shared from a time

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-fql

We can use FQL › link_stat to query the total numbers. Can we give a specified time to query？

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

Answer (score 0):

No, the only indexable field, the fields you can specify on the where clause, is `url`.  Indexable fields are marked with a asterix '*' in Facebook's documentation.